MS Graph SDK v5: adding value to singleValueExtendedProperties (contacts)
I'm trying to add value to several singleValueExtendedProperties  when creating new contacts with Graph SDK v5 (C#). My code run without error, but it seems like singleValueExtendedProperties is not applied.
For example, If I run the bellow code it works.
var requestContactBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.Contact
{
    Surname = "",
    GivenName = givenName,
    FileAs = givenName,
    CompanyName = companyName,
    JobTitle = jobTitle,
    Department = department,
    BusinessHomePage = businessHomePage,
    BusinessPhones = new List<string>(),
    MobilePhone = mobilePhone,
    EmailAddresses = new List<Microsoft.Graph.Models.EmailAddress>
    {
        new Microsoft.Graph.Models.EmailAddress
        {
            Name = emailAddress_name,
            Address = emailAddress_address,
        },
    },
    BusinessAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.PhysicalAddress
    {
        Street = businessAddress_street,
        City = businessAddress_city,
        State = businessAddress_state,
        PostalCode = businessAddress_postalCode,
    },
    PersonalNotes = personalNotes,
    SingleValueExtendedProperties = new List<Microsoft.Graph.Models.SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty>
    {
        new Microsoft.Graph.Models.SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty
        {
            Id = "String {00062004-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Id 0x8084",
            Value = aSemail,
        },
        new Microsoft.Graph.Models.SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty
        {
            Id = "String {00062004-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} Id 0x8082",
            Value = "SMTP",
        },
    },
};

gsc.Users[impersonaddr].ContactFolders[aFolderID].Contacts.PostAsync(requestContactBody).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

However, If the check the just added contacts through graph explorer, singleValueExtendedProperties aren't applied correctly while others are fine.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String {00062004-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Id 0x00008084' or id eq 'String {00062004-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Id 0x8082')

It seems like they are set to default value.
"singleValueExtendedProperties": [
    {
        "id": "String {00062004-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} Id 0x8084",
        "value": "gisa1@example.com"
    },
    {
        "id": "String {00062004-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} Id 0x8082",
        "value": "EX"
    }
]

Anyone help me please

I figure it out! For SingleValueExtendedProperties PostAsync dosen't work.
You should create contact with POST first and then add SingleValueExtendedProperties using PATCH.
For example,
var contactResult = gsc.Users[impersonaddr].ContactFolders[aFolderID].Contacts.PostAsync(requestContactBody).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    
var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.Contact
{
    SingleValueExtendedProperties = new List<Microsoft.Graph.Models.SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty>
    {
        new Microsoft.Graph.Models.SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty
        {
            Id = "String {00062004-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Id 0x8084",
            Value = aSemail,
        },
        new Microsoft.Graph.Models.SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty
        {
            Id = "String {00062004-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} Id 0x8082",
            Value = "SMTP",
        },
    },
};

gsc.Users[impersonaddr].Contacts[contactResult.Id].PatchAsync(requestBody).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); 

